# How to call one file from another file in protractor angular

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

This is the first file
log.js

```
var user = 'raghavendra@gmail.com', pwd = '123';

describe(' login page.', function() {

    it('Sending a valid values:', function() {
        browser.get('http://gmail.com');

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual()
```

second file 
create_file.js

```
describe(' login page.', function() {
    it('Sending a valid values:', function() {
}
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual()
}
```

How to call log.js file in create_file.js.  Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution

```
require('/home/raghavendra/Desktop/python_pro/ng_test/e2e-tests/log.js');
```